# Filter values from a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of input data `'list_data'`, by means of a code and based on a criterion I establish pairs of data `'pairs'`, which in my case give a total of 29, but among those data there are some pairs that should ***NOT be in the list***.

```
list_data = [[ 1, 'Col', 'A', 'B'], 
             [ 2, 'Col', 'E', 'F'], 
             [ 3, 'Col', 'I', 'J'], 
             [ 4, 'Col', 'M', 'N'], 
             [ 5, 'Col', 'B', 'C'], 
             [ 6, 'Col', 'F', 'G'], 
             [ 7, 'Col', 'J', 'K'], 
             [ 8, 'Col', 'N', 'O'], 
             [ 9, 'Col', 'C', 'D'], 
             [10, 'Col', 'G', 'H'], 
             [11, 'Col', 'K', 'L'], 
             [12, 'Col', 'O', 'P'], 
             [13, 'Row', 'B', 'F'], 
             [14, 'Row', 'F', 'J'], 
             [15, 'Row', 'J', 'N'], 
             [16, 'Row', 'C', 'G'], 
             [17, 'Row', 'G', 'K'], 
             [18, 'Row', 'K', 'O'], 
             [19, 'Row', 'D', 'H'], 
             [20, 'Row', 'H', 'L'], 
             [21, 'Row', 'L', 'P']]

pairs = []
for i in range(len(list_data)):
    for j in range(len(list_data)):
        if list_data[i][2] == list_data[j][3]:  
            pairs.append([list_data[i][0], list_data[j][0]])
print(pairs)
print(len(pairs))

print('','\n')
            
filter_one = []
for i in range(len(list_data)):
    for n in range(len(pairs)):
        if pairs[n][0] == list_data[i][0] and pairs[n][1] == list_data[i][0] and list_data[i][1] == 'Col':
            filter_one.append([pairs[n][0], pairs[n][1]])
print(filter_one)
print(len(filter_one))
```

To eliminate them I do it using the following criteria:

*If **both values of each pair belong to `'Row'`** then I will remove them.* In my case I should have `29 - 6 = 23` pairs.

My problem is that when programming this logic I get an empty list.

I would really appreciate if you can help me with the solution and in the meantime giving feedback to my error. Best regards.

**Note: Illustration of the objective of the result:**

```
#I currently print this list:
[[5, 1], [6, 2], [6, 13], [7, 3], [7, 14], [8, 4], [8, 15], [9, 5], [ 10, 6], [10, 16], [11, 7], [11, 17], [12, 8], [12, 18], [13, 1], [14, 2], [14, 13], [15, 3], [15, 14], [16, 5], [17, 6], [17, 16], [18, 7], [18, 17], [19, 9] , [20, 10], [20, 19], [21, 11], [21, 20]]

#I am looking to print this list:
[[5, 1], [6, 2], [6, 13], [7, 3], [7, 14], [8, 4], [8, 15], [9, 5], [ 10, 6], [10, 16], [11, 7], [11, 17], [12, 8], [12, 18], [13, 1], [14, 2], [15, 3], [16, 5], [17, 6], [18, 17], [19, 9], [20, 10], [21, 11]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how:

```
list_data = [[ 1, 'Col', 'A', 'B'], 
             [ 2, 'Col', 'E', 'F'], 
             [ 3, 'Col', 'I', 'J'], 
             [ 4, 'Col', 'M', 'N'], 
             [ 5, 'Col', 'B', 'C'], 
             [ 6, 'Col', 'F', 'G'], 
             [ 7, 'Col', 'J', 'K'], 
             [ 8, 'Col', 'N', 'O'], 
             [ 9, 'Col', 'C', 'D'], 
             [10, 'Col', 'G', 'H'], 
             [11, 'Col', 'K', 'L'], 
             [12, 'Col', 'O', 'P'], 
             [13, 'Row', 'B', 'F'], 
             [14, 'Row', 'F', 'J'], 
             [15, 'Row', 'J', 'N'], 
             [16, 'Row', 'C', 'G'], 
             [17, 'Row', 'G', 'K'], 
             [18, 'Row', 'K', 'O'], 
             [19, 'Row', 'D', 'H'], 
             [20, 'Row', 'H', 'L'], 
             [21, 'Row', 'L', 'P']]

pairs = []
for i,l in enumerate(list_data): # For index, list in list_data
    for j,k in enumerate(list_data): # For index, list in list_data
        if l[2] == k[3] and not (l[1]==k[1]=='Row'): # if the 2nd index of the first list equals to the third index of the 2nd list and if the 1 index of both lists aren't `Row`
            pairs.append([list_data[i][0], list_data[j][0]])
print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
[[5, 1], [6, 2], [6, 13], [7, 3], [7, 14], [8, 4], [8, 15], [9, 5], [10, 6], [10, 16], [11, 7], [11, 17], [12, 8], [12, 18], [13, 1], [14, 2], [15, 3], [16, 5], [17, 6], [18, 7], [19, 9], [20, 10], [21, 11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and list destructuring, doing everything in one pass (still nested loop though):

```py
list_data = [[ 1, 'Col', 'A', 'B'], 
             [ 2, 'Col', 'E', 'F'], 
             [ 3, 'Col', 'I', 'J'], 
             [ 4, 'Col', 'M', 'N'], 
             [ 5, 'Col', 'B', 'C'], 
             [ 6, 'Col', 'F', 'G'], 
             [ 7, 'Col', 'J', 'K'], 
             [ 8, 'Col', 'N', 'O'], 
             [ 9, 'Col', 'C', 'D'], 
             [10, 'Col', 'G', 'H'], 
             [11, 'Col', 'K', 'L'], 
             [12, 'Col', 'O', 'P'], 
             [13, 'Row', 'B', 'F'], 
             [14, 'Row', 'F', 'J'], 
             [15, 'Row', 'J', 'N'], 
             [16, 'Row', 'C', 'G'], 
             [17, 'Row', 'G', 'K'], 
             [18, 'Row', 'K', 'O'], 
             [19, 'Row', 'D', 'H'], 
             [20, 'Row', 'H', 'L'], 
             [21, 'Row', 'L', 'P']]

pairs = [
    [index_i, index_j]
    for index_i, col_or_row_i, first_letter_i, second_letter_i in list_data
    for index_j, col_or_row_j, first_letter_j, second_letter_j in list_data
    if not col_or_row_i == col_or_row_j == "Row" and first_letter_i == second_letter_j
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you create the pairs (your code up to where you do `print(len(pairs))`) works correctly, so there is no need to change that.

To remove the pairs that contain two rows, it will be helpful to start by creating a dictionary (I called `is_row`) which maps a number onto a boolean which says whether that number is a row or not. You can then use this dictionary to make a list of pairs that need to be removed, and remove them:

```
is_row = dict((t[0], t[1] == 'Row') for t in list_data)

remove_pairs = [p for p in pairs if is_row[p[0]] and is_row[p[1]]]

for p in remove_pairs:
    pairs.remove(p)
```

After doing this, `pairs` contains:

```
[[5, 1], [6, 2], [6, 13], [7, 3], [7, 14], [8, 4], [8, 15], [9, 5], [10, 6], [10, 16], [11, 7], [11, 17], [12, 8], [12, 18], [13, 1], [14, 2], [15, 3], [16, 5], [17, 6], [18, 7], [19, 9], [20, 10], [21, 11]]
```

Here is what the `is_row` dictionary looks like:

```
{1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False, 6: False, 7: False, 8: False, 9: False, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: True, 14: True, 15: True, 16: True, 17: True, 18: True, 19: True, 20: True, 21: True}
```

and here is the `remove_pairs` list:

```
[[14, 13], [15, 14], [17, 16], [18, 17], [20, 19], [21, 20]]
```

### And to answer the question about what you are doing wrong:

Here is a modified version of your code, with the two errors corrected:

1. you need to loop over *two* indices in the `list_data` because the pairs are not both at the same index (I called `i` and `j`)
2. you also need to test whether *either* of them are "Col" (you are only testing the second one)

I could suggest further changes, but here is the minimum change needed to fix the problem.

```
filter_one = []
for i in range(len(list_data)):
    for j in range(len(list_data)):  # <=== Loop over j 
        for n in range(len(pairs)):

            if (pairs[n][0] == list_data[i][0]
                and pairs[n][1] == list_data[j][0] # <== using j here
                and (list_data[i][1] == 'Col'         # <== 
                     or list_data[j][1] == 'Col')):   # <== 

                filter_one.append([pairs[n][0], pairs[n][1]])
```